# How to edit code min

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
 int main()
    {
        float gets[8];
        int i;
        char mes;
        printf("Enter 7 numbers into the vector:");
        for(i=0 ; i<7 ; i++)
        scanf("%f" ,&gets);
float min=0;
 int v;
 for(v=0 ; v<7 ; v++)
 {
 if (min > gets[v])
    min = gets[v];
 }

printf("%f" ,min);
```

how to edit code .c code how to possible to condition

 i fill 7 number ,But min = 0 every time.

Comment: Please clarify your question, I can hardly tell what your trying to say.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing wrong parameter to the function `scanf()`.

The address of each element you want to input should be passed to `scanf()`.

You want to fill `gets[i]` for `i=0,..6`.

Address of an element is found using `&` operator.

```
scanf("%f" ,&gets[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @coderedoc answer you need to make the following changes.

Change `float min=0;` to `float min=gets[0];` - Ie. The current minimum is the first value in the array. Then change `for(v=0 ; v<7 ; v++)` to `for(v=1 ; v<7 ; v++)` as you do not need to consider the first value.

In addition it is probably not a good idea to use `gets` as a variable name as there is a function of the same name - [gets](https://linux.die.net/man/3/gets)

Comment: It would be even worse to be using the function `gets()`.  It's a tricky area, but the variable makes sure the function isn't abused.  Of course, shadowing (variables inside a function hiding variables — or functions — defined outside the function) can be a problem.